# Terraform: how to do math within resource

Tags: syntax, terraform, hcl

I have a resource, and within it I use `count`.  I need to add one to the count, and cannot figure out the syntax.

**Background**

Up until now I have been doing this:

```
resource "signalfx_time_chart" "my_chart" {
    count = 6
    name = "Chart #${count.index + 1}"
}
```

*Note*: this is a simplification, actually within the resource I use `count.index + 1` quite often.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
resource "signalfx_time_chart" "my_chart" {
    count = 6
    index = count.index + 1
    name = "Chart #${index}"
}
```

However, this doesn't work for me, as the syntax is incorrect.

I don't think it's relevant to the question, but just in case, this is the resource I am using: [signalfx_time_chart](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/signalfx/r/time_chart.html)

***Edit for clarity***: What I would like to do involves the following:

- Adding `index` (or some similar name), which is not an argument for the resource `signalfx_time_chart`
- Doing math on `count.index` and setting the result to `index`

**Question**

My question is sort of two-fold:

1. How do I add in a local variable (Ex: `index`)
2. How do I set it to be `count.index + 1`?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't do this. Locals are global to the rest of the Terraform context so don't know about the more tightly scoped index of the resource.

Comment: I think the asker is misusing the term "local variable" here, which is causing confusion. For the question, I do not understand why you want to do this. It seems like your original resource is the correct way to go. Also, there is no `index` argument for the `signalfx_time_chart` when I check the documentation, so is this question purely hypothetical?

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the confusion.  This is not a hypothetical question.  Basically, in one resource I retype `count.index + 1` so many times, and I wanted a "local variable" within the resource to just simplify things, make lines shorter, and more readable.  I also edited my question to add clarity @MattSchuchard

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I am new to Terraform, but basically I just want a temporary variable in the resource that gets re-evaluated when `count.index` increments.  I am not sure if this is possible, or the syntax for it

Comment: Yeah not possible sadly. And @MattSchuchard `local` always felt like a bad name for it in my opinion.